# What is the linguistic or scriptural background of Jesus using cup in Matthew 26:39?

Tags: jesus, gospels, crucifixion

Here are some scriptural references (quotes from ESV).  The cup seems to refer often to one's portion of God's will.  Any incites on the use of the term cup.

> And going a little farther he fell on his face and prayed, saying, “My Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me; nevertheless, not as I will, but as you will.
> (Matt. 26:39)

> And he said to her, “What do you want?” She said to him, “Say that these two sons of mine are to sit, one at your right hand and one at your left, in your kingdom.”  Jesus answered, “You do not know what you are asking. Are you able to drink the cup that I am to drink?” They said to him, “We are able.”  He said to them, “You will drink my cup, but to sit at my right hand and at my left is not mine to grant, but it is for those for whom it has been prepared by my Father.”
> (Matt 20:21–23)

```
               You prepare a table before me 
  in the presence of my enemies; 
              you anoint my head with oil; 
  my cup overflows. 
               Surely goodness and mercy shall follow me 
  all the days of my life, 
              and I shall dwell in the house of the LORD 
  forever. 
                       (Ps 23:5–6)



        The LORD is my chosen portion and my cup; 
  you hold my lot. 
                (Psalm 16:5)

        I will lift up the cup of salvation 
  and call on the name of the LORD, 
                (Psalm 116:13)
```

> And he took a cup, and when he had given thanks he said, “Take this, and divide it among yourselves.  For I tell you that from now on I will not drink of the fruit of the vine until the kingdom of God comes.”  And he took bread, and when he had given thanks, he broke it and gave it to them, saying, “This is my body, which is given for you. Do this in remembrance of me.”  And likewise the cup after they had eaten, saying, “This cup that is poured out for you is the new covenant in my blood.
> (Luke 22:17–20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not used literally, "cup" ποτήριον is a figure/metaphor of one's destiny whether good or bad.  Indeed, BDAG states this (so does Thayer) when it says:

> in the OT, ποτήριον is an expression for destiny in both a good and
> bad senses, for death in general ... On the concept of drinking a cup
> of suffering cp. Isa 51:17, 22; Lam 4:21,; Ps 10:6; 74:9 ...

in the NT we see exactly the same metaphor: "*shall I not drink the cup the Father has given me?*" John 18:11; see also Matt 20:22, 26:39, 42, Mark 10:38, 14:36, Luke 22:42, etc.

Thus, Jesus, at the last supper, appears to combine two common Jewish metaphors - one from the Passover, and the other from Hebrew poetry about destiny, into a new powerful Christian symbol of the New covenant:

- Luke 22:20 - and the cup likewise, after having supped, saying, "This **cup is the new covenant** in My blood, which is being poured out for you.
- 1 Cor 11:25 - Likewise also the cup after having supped, saying, "This **cup is the new covenant** in My blood; do this, as often as you might drink it, in remembrance of Me."

Thus, "the cup" of the last supper:

- provides a link to its origins in the Passover
- uses a well-known metaphor of Jesus voluntarily deciding to suffer the destiny of death and suffering
- becomes a reminder to future participants of the spilled blood of Jesus
- becomes a symbol of the sacrifice of Jesus and how it is to affect the hearts of Jesus followers as per Heb 8:10, 10:16, Jer 31:31

Comment: +1 I knew someone would have some insight on this.